# Individual Apple Developer accounts in a Team with two members

Tags: ios, xcode, publish

Can two Individuals, both with paid Individual Developer Accounts create a team so that they both are able to submit updates to the app, without having to go to the route of registering an Enterprise account?

It seems not - the issue is that the second person can't get access to the provisioning profile for the app ID - unless I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

No. Thats the point of having an Enterprise Account. While on individual, only one account can have provisioning files. Workaround is to login in both machines with the same account, which is something not recommended.